# kafka s3 sink connector keys and headers s3 storage write not working

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

I have enabled

```
"store.kafka.keys" : "true",
"store.kafka.headers" : "true",
"keys.format.class" : "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
"headers.format.class" : "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat"
```

But I don't see the headers, keys  in the s3 storage. Only values part is stored.

Any input will greatly help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've installed the latest version of the S3 sink connector.

It used to only write the values prior to (approximately) version 10.x